# Multiline text overflow hidden with footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

Hi there I have a flex container with some elements in it and one of them should be a div with a title, a content composed of an image and a long text, and a footer.

All of the elements should be the same height and I am experiencing trouble making this precise div the right height. You can check it [here](https://codepen.io/Mowso/pen/ZEQdvZx)

You can see I have a border around my div `#article` and the text with the footer is crossing it. I would like the text to be like `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but with no `white-space: nowrap;` and the footer to be on the border so all children of my flex container

Comment: Depending on the browsers you need to support, you may want to use [clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) or [line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `max-height` on `#une, #article, #important` and place it on `.contentArticle .textArticle` but you won't have the ellipsis.

The `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is tricky when you want multiple lines displayed.

There is a tutorial on how to do it only with css here: https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-truncation-with-pure-css/
Or you can use Javascript